# How can I get a notification on a new Chrome / Firefox / Safari version?

Tags: browser

Looking for a way to get a notification every time that Chrome, Firefox and Safari releases a new version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use below path,

1. On your computer, open

> particular browser

.
 2. At the top right, click More Settings.
 3. At the bottom, click Advanced.
 4. Under "Privacy and security," click Content settings.
 5. Click Notifications. Allow it.

It will give you all notifications about browser.